# How can I argparse a file content to a url

Tags: python

`
import requests
import argparse

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-u" )
parser.add_argument( "-f" , type=open)
args = parser.parse_args()
target = args.u
wordlist = args.f

def loop():
        for word in wordlist:
            print(word)
            res = requests.get(url=f"{target}/{word}")
            print(word)
            print(res)
            if res.status_code == 404:
                loop()
            else:
                data = res.json()
                print(data)
                print(res.status_code)
                print(word)
        
loop()
```

`

I try to open a file using argparser and get the words to add at the end of my url request.
but even if the url is valid I get 404 response instead of getting 200 response

Comment: What arguments do you give it?

Comment: I use it like this: python test.py -u "a target URL" -f "wordlist file path"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes because you're iterating over the file object itself rather than the actual lines of the file! So I'll use `argparse.FileType('r')` as the argument type for `-f`, which allows me to read the file and get its lines using `readlines()`,after that I'll iterate over the lines of the file and strip any leading/trailing whitespace or newline characters from each word before making the request!

check this out:

```
import requests
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-u")
parser.add_argument("-f", type=argparse.FileType('r'))
args = parser.parse_args()
target = args.u
wordlist = args.f.readlines()

def loop():
    for word in wordlist:
        word = word.strip()  #removing any leading/trailing whitespace or newline characters
        print(word)
        res = requests.get(url=f"{target}/{word}")
        print(res)
        if res.status_code == 404:
            continue
        else:
            data = res.json()
            print(data)
            print(res.status_code)
            print(word)

loop()
```